# php build error: please reinstall BZip2 distribution

Tags: software-installation, php, bzip2

I tried to build PHP v8.0.0 from its source but after running `./configure` it says:

```
...
checking for BZip2... not found
configure: error: please reinstall BZip2 distribution
```

But I have `bzip2` installed already. How do I fix that?

Comment: The answer may be https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/issues/786#issuecomment-245622916. That is, PHP requires bzip2 libraries, not the bzip2 command.

Comment: Please install `bzip2-devel` or if Debian / Ubuntu `libbz2-dev` ...... I.e. packages for "building something" is always (lib)name-**dev***

Comment: Installing `libbz2-dev` solved this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please install `bzip2-devel`, or if it's about Debian , Ubuntu , Mint the package name is `libbz2-dev` .

I.e. packages for "building something" is always `(lib)name-dev*`